# add groups from external file

Tags: shell-script, python, group

I want to write a script which add groups to the system, specified in `groups.txt` file.
content of **groups.txt** :

> group01 : computer
>        group02 : electronics
>        group03 : IT
>        .
>        .
>        .
>        .
>        group13 : instrumentation
>      group14 : EOF

any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Please do not add code snippets in-line in comments. Edit your OP and add what you've done in code blocks.

Comment: after running my script I get following:                                                  `Usage: groupadd [options] $GROUP` and list of options.

Comment: Im using `grep "group0$num" $path | cut -f2 -d:` in while loop until it greps `EOF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '!/EOF/{print $1}' groups.txt|xargs -i groupadd {}
```

If you wanted the name of the group to be e.g. IT (note that most unix/linux systems won't allow upper case names) just change the statement like so:

```
awk '!/EOF/{print $3}' groups.txt|xargs -i groupadd {}
```

Comment: IT and others are just example. I want to extract a word computer,electronics,it,etc. from text file and that will be added as groupadd to my system. ?

Comment: And that's exactly what the 2nd version will do.

Comment: No groups has added to the system...

Comment: Which user are you running it as? Got any errors?

Comment: No Im not getting any error, but to verify that whether group has been added to system, I checked `/etc/group` file, but there was no such group present in it.

Comment: Im running this as `root` user. when I run `awk '!/EOF/{print $3}' groups.txt` I get blank screen, I mean 11 white lines as a output

Comment: And the file-format matches what you put in your question?  What does **awk '!/EOF/{print $3}' groups.txt** print?

Comment: Nothing is printed... 11 white lines.. thats it

Comment: and your file format is groupXX SPACE COLON SPACE name?

Comment: no there was printing mistake in my question.. there is no SPACE between. It is `groupXX:<groupname>`

Comment: Im able to print computer,electronics,it etc. as per your suggestion `awk '!/EOF/{print $3}' groups.txt`, now how to add this group iteratively in loop ?

Comment: Thank You...This worked..!! actually there was mistake in my `groups.txt` file. +1